# How to create tables from jdbc program in hortonworks using Hive?

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I want to create table in Hive by using JDBC. This is the code I tried,

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveClient {
private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public static void main(String[] args) {
Connection con=null;
  // Register driver and create driver instance
try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
      // get connection
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true/userdb", "root", "dc123");

     // create statement
     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

  // execute statement
  stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
     +" employee ( eid int, name String, "
     +" salary String, destignation String)"
     +" COMMENT ‘Employee details’"
     +" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED"
     +" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’"
     +" LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’"
     +" STORED AS TEXTFILE;");

  System.out.println(" Table employee created.");
  con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}

 }
}
```

This program shows an Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think that you have to use: `private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";`

Comment: @hisi But should i add any external jars? It still shows class not found exception.

Comment: You have to replace  `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` by `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the connection string worked for me

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:hive2://58.184.82.67:10000/default", "", "");
```

In pom.xml added 3 dependencies,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
<artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
<version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
<version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you've copied code from a MySQL connection example, and tried to replace the query with HiveQL, which will not work.

Neither `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or `jdbc:mysql` will let you connect to Hive. 
See Hive wiki on [Using JDBC](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2%2BClients#HiveServer2Clients-UsingJDBC) to connect to Hive.

---

The error simply means your classpath doesn't have the MySQL Driver on the classpath. Even if you changed the string, you'd get a similar error for Hive.

I strongly suggest using Maven or Gradle to load your dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

Additionally `sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/hive` needs a port number like `sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:10000/hive` plus you do not need `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true/userdb`. Nor are the user credentials for Hive `root/dc123` on the sandbox.

---

If you are trying to connect to the Hive **metastore**, which I believe is running PostgreSQL in the Hortonworks Sandbox, then again, you're using the wrong JDBC driver, connection URL, query syntax, and server port information.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007